Strange hallucination of Copilot on the simple question about ffmpeg
Did anyone encounter something like this? I am citing my dialogue with MS Copilot.

Please generate a ffmpeg command to add the old analog camera effect to the video and slow it 5 times


To add an old analog camera effect to a video and slow it down by 5 times using ffmpeg, you can use the following command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "curves=vintage,noise=alls=20:allf=t+u,setpts=5PTS" -af "atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5" -c:a copy output.mp4
This command will: -i input.mp4: Specify the input video file. -vf "curves=vintage,noise=alls=20:allf=t+u,setpts=5PTS": Apply a vintage curve filter for the retro color effect, add noise to simulate analog video grain, and increase the presentation timestamp (PTS) to slow down the video by 5 times. -af "atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5": Slow down the audio. Since atempo filter can only slow down by a factor of 0.5 to 2.0, you need to apply it twice to achieve the 0.2 speed (which is 1/5th of the original speed). -c:a copy: Copy the audio stream without re-encoding. output.mp4: Specify the output video file.
Make sure to replace input.mp4 with the actual name of your video file. The setpts filter is used for video speed adjustment, and the atempo filter is used for audio speed adjustment. Since ffmpeg does not allow audio speed changes below 0.5x in a single step, you need to chain the atempo filter to reduce the speed further. Adjust the parameters as needed for your specific requirements.


Please add to this command line the part that allows to add to the video overcontrast effect that starts from the contrast values when the video is very, very over-contrasted, and by the end of the video it should come to normal

...and here is the last reply:
and (, of which,, ** the a, the- up of to w

or Ien . You. inde. Yes,ish s, a Sa. of AT a while back and for. table on the fit there is in as that guidedo in V family

. They o.. not  for.  a g-  ( pils am the| repeatedly FM out, st gam d in confer . on a the, and the. to Des to .  for the a

& ke… or . the CAS art theen prime del the with to! re on onit States out, ofkssic -,. this,un atlantic for of c. In

I am intrigued. What do you think about this?

Does this answer your question? Why the Llama 2 language model keeps printing random garbage text when certain prompts are used?

Unfortunately no, there is some garbage in the context memory I guess
